# Sync US server with EU server

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization

Today I've had an idea:

I wanted to set up a vps in the US, I do already have one in the EU.

The EU server has the master mysql database, the US server should become the slave database.

To fix offsyncing there must be some sort of realtime syncronisation. I was thinking about taking svn and mysql dump and import it into the slave system using cronned jobs.

Posting should take a plugin for phpbb and post into my EU mysql server. This way I can speed up the forum in the US because it's 200ms slower.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm using ubuntu server 10.04, apache2, php5-mysql and subversion.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: "Today I've had an idea:" - well done! Don't over do it though....

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but [MySQL Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html) might help.